# How to style features depending on comparison operators in Leaflet

Tags: switch-statement, leaflet

All the examples I find online that talk about how to style a feature depending on one of its properties use a switch statement that evaluates whether that property corresponds to a specific value.

For example this is taken form [one of Leaflet's](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) official tutorials:

```
L.geoJSON(states, {
style: function(feature) {
    switch (feature.properties.party) {
        case 'Republican': return {color: "#ff0000"};
        case 'Democrat':   return {color: "#0000ff"};
    }
}
}).addTo(map);
```

What if I wanted to determine the feature's color depending on a numeric treshold? Say all features that have propertyX (which is a number) bigger than a certain value get colored red, otherwise blue.

I found [this post](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/513a15984beaecc38e000cd1) where one user explains that switch statements are not made for comparisons; how can I do one then?

If use an external function (see code below) the latter seems to not be able to access the feature's properties.

```
L.geoJSON(states, {
    style: styling
    }).addTo(map);

function styling () {
    if (feature.properties.numericProp > 100) {
        return {color: "red"}
    } else {
        return {color: "blue"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature gets passed a parameter of your function, you forgot to add it:

```
function styling (feature) {
    // feature is now available
}
```

Comment: Correct! Thanks..
Just a note if anyone is trying to do the same the pattern to access a features property is:
   function styling (feature) {
       // feature is now available
        var myProp = feature.properties.myProp;
        if (myProp > treshold) { //do something ; }
            }